# How to delete rows from another table in SQLITE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join, inner-join, sql-delete

I have these tables

**AT_WAR** Primary key Ship_Name and War_ID

| Ship_Name | War_ID |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 2 |
| Third | 3 |

**SHIP** Primary key Ship_Name

| Ship_Name | Ship_Type_ID |
| --- | --- |
| First | S.1 |
| Second | S.2 |
| Third | S.3 |
| FOURTH | S.4 |

I want from the SHIP table to delete the ships that did not take part in a war.
If i want to show the ships that participates in a war i can use this command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SHIP.Ship_Name FROM SHIP
INNER JOIN AT_WAR ON SHIP.Ship_Name = AT_WAR.Ship_Name
```

I am using this command but did not work

```
DELETE FROM SHIP 
INNER JOIN AT_WAR ON SHIP.Ship_Name = AT_WAR.Ship_Name
WHERE AT_WAR.Ship_Name IS NULL;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not support joins in the `DELETE` statement (yet), so one option is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM SHIP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AT_WAR WHERE AT_WAR.Ship_Name = SHIP.Ship_Name);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ea893a2eee8b2b8f281e80e39281ff9c).

Or, `NOT IN`:

```
DELETE FROM SHIP
WHERE Ship_Name NOT IN (SELECT Ship_Name FROM AT_WAR);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2b4a754ec51ae9e9b90bbf2893c4cbf9).